# Error generating ng-repeat using a descending order filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object that I try to filter the data from highest to lowest and limiting it to 8. I am getting this error that I do not know how to solve. What is happening and how can I solve it? thank you very much.

https://jsfiddle.net/bg3mkwvL/

```
  <div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat='item in people | orderBy: "-score" | limitTo: 8'>
    <p>
      {{item.name}}  {{item.score}}
    </p>
  </div>

  $scope.people={ 
    "juan": { "name": "juan", "score":0},
    "pedro": { "name": "pedro", "score":0},
    "goku": { "name": "goku", "score":0},
  }
```

I need to use this syntax:

```
"juan": {"name": "juan", "score": 0}
```

Then I need to write for example '

```
 console.log ($scope.people['juan'])
```

and I need get the Object without having to make cycles.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can modify your json object array as below;

```
$scope.people= [
  { "name": "juan", "score":0},
  { "name": "pedro", "score":0},
  { "name": "goku", "score":0},
]
```

Comment: but thats the copy of my answer :(

Comment: yes true. I dint notice that... removed my answer. ^1

Comment: @Dr.Geek I need to use this syntax:

"juan": {"name": "juan", "score": 0}
Then I need to write for example console.log ($scope.people['juan']) and I need get the Object without having to make cycles.

Comment: If you want to use such a syntax like that, you have to create a specific  pipe module for this specific syntax. You can read http://hashtagcoder.com/an-introduction-to-angular-cli-part-3-sort-and-filter-data-with-custom-pipes/ , https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176188/angular2-sorting-pipe-with-object-array

Comment: @Dr.Geek I can not understand you, can you explain it to me again, please?

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to transform your data into a logical manner to iterate the array.

**Working Plnkr -** http://plnkr.co/edit/obGuS8Cg28roOaNzrzfV?p=preview

Code iteration -

```
$scope.listData = $scope.people.map(function(data){
  var tmp = Object.keys(data);
  return data[tmp];
})
```

**Code -**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);


app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
      $scope.people= [
        {
          "juan": { "name": "juan", "score":8}
        },
        {
          "pedro": { "name": "pedro", "score":2}
        },
        {
          "goku": { "name": "goku", "score":7}
        },
      ];
      
      $scope.listData = $scope.people.map(function(data){
        var tmp = Object.keys(data);
        return data[tmp];
      })
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.1" data-semver="1.6.1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat='data in listData | orderBy: "-score"'>
        <p>
          {{data.name}}  {{data.score}}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: great! thank you, but I need to use this syntax:

"juan": {"name": "juan", "score": 0}
Then I need to write for example '

 console.log ($scope.people['juan'])  and I need get the Object without having to make cycles. how can do it? in your code.

Comment: @yavg what do you mean by ` I need get the Object without having to make cycles.` ?

Comment: for example I need (this is the object "juan1": {"name": "juan", "score": 0})  console.log ($scope.people['juan1'].name)=='juan'   okay?

Comment: without cycle for for example, this is direct

Comment: for(var i in $scope.people){ if  $scope.people[i].name=='juan} I do not want to do it this way

Comment: @yavg have you checked my code I am not using this for loop

Comment: @yavg You can do like this => `console.log($scope.people[0]['juan']);  console.log($scope.people[1]['pedro']);`

Comment: This will give you - `{ "name": "juan", "score":8}` & `{ "name": "pedro", "score":2}`

Comment: Exactly, this is what I need. But in my real problem, I get the key, and with the key I access the object. In other words I do not know what the index is

Comment: I get the key, not the index in my real problem..  for that "juan": {"name": "juan", "score": 0}

Comment: You need to use loop as index will only be available to you then....I believe you need to revisit the logic ..as I guess might be it will help you out ..as per your question I guess I provided you an answer

Answer (score 0):

From **AngularJS 1.4** this is the implementation of ordering in `ng-repeat` for objects

> Version 1.4 removed the alphabetic sorting. We now rely on the order
>   returned by the browser when running for key in myObj.

So if you can't change the structure of your model, re order the object in order to put the score as the first property:

```
$scope.people={ 
    "juan": { "score": 2, "name": "juan" },
    "pedro": { "score":0, "name": "pedro" },
    "goku": { "score":1, "name": "goku" }
  }
```

And it should work even with your structure without specifying any `orderBy`in the `ng-repeat`

If you want to reorder the object dynamically, you can do the following:

```
for (var key in $scope.people) {
  $scope.people[key] = Object.assign({score: $scope.people[key].score}, $scope.people[key]);
}
```